# image enhancement to read car plate

Tags: image-quality, image-manipulation, restoration

A group of thieves entered in my house and robbed a lot of my stuff.
They used a car to run away. The following images were obtained from CCV cameras from neighbors. Is it possible to improve those images so we are able read the car plate? [image]

[image]

[image][image]

Comment: I think you've to contact these guys [CSI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CSI:_Crime_Scene_Investigation), see an example of their work [here](https://qph.is.quoracdn.net/main-qimg-f75ea0eb5c221a730fd0c48e38ee7718?convert_to_webp=true). *Sorry about your lose. My comment is only as a humor.*

Comment: If you have access to the original video - you may be able to use multiple frames to create a composite frame that enables the plate to be read.

Comment: Please try to get the entire video from the neighbors CCTV.  If you can, then you can use crops from the neighboring frames the create a super-resolution image. For example, PhotoAcute can morph images to register and align the images, then interpolate the images to give you better results.  Depending upon the images, you may need to deconvolve them (cf FocusMagic) and/or remove some motion blur before you try to 'stack' the images. Or, you may create the super-resolution image, then try to remove blur.   Is it possible to get us the original, uncompressed video?

Comment: Is that line of ?holes? across the front of the bonnet standard for that model of car? I've not seen anything like that before.

Comment: A look through many images using : brazil hatchback and brazil wagon does not show one like that. High rear lights unusual. Ford Fiesta like but different. May be rare. Model/brand =?

Comment: @RussellMcMahon I suspect you're seeing an issue with the low resolution and a [moiré pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moiré_pattern) showing up in what is a line in one direction that doesn't align with the scan line of the image capture.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because photos should be given to the police which then can take further steps.

Answer (score 2):

Given that the pictures seem to be low resolution, no- the plate in the camera 3 shots is just a big blur. If the resolution was higher so that you could distinguish the letters and numbers as individual blurs, you might be able to get something by using deconvolution.

Comment: as an example of what can rsp. can't be done, see focus magic's own homepage: http://www.focusmagic.com/forensics-tutorial.htm